# Dependency errors while installing SDL2

Tags: sdl

I want use SDL2 in my project. For that I need lib and include SDL2 files. I was trying to install SDL2 with

```
apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

but get an errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpulse-dev : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:14.2-1ubuntu1) but 1:14.2-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (= 1:14.2-1ubuntu1) but 1:14.2-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How I can fix it?

Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 21.04
Release: 21.04
Codename: hirsute

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 21.04
Release: 21.04
Codename: hirsute

Comment: In my question, I wrote that I want to install which command I do it and gave an error log. Please tell me what exactly is not clear to you.

Comment: @mejay48 Try this `sudo sed -i.bak 's/\(^deb.*-updates.*\)/#\1/' /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt install libsdl2-dev`.

Comment: It seems updates channel prompt you to install `1:14.2-1ubuntu1.1` version, hence why i try disabling it. I could be wrong though, you can try `apt-get -s install libsdl2-dev` to simulate the process before actually running them.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it does not help me. with your command line I got exacly same errors.

Comment: Minor version errors like this *usually* occur because the package catalog needs to be updated (`sudo apt update`)

Comment: unfortunately no, apt update does not fix issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

So, I can't find a reason of errors of sdl2 package, but manual compilation from source helps me install it (./configure, sudo make install).